# Best practice for Qt Quick application

Tags: qt, qt-quick

I'm new to Qt and I come from MVVM Windows applications. I'm wondering if there's a "best practice" architecture for Qt Quick applications, similar to Views, ViewModels, etc, for seperating views from program logic.

Is it common to implement functions in the mainwindow file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [good link](http://www.ics.com/blog/multilayered-architecture-qt-quick) to start, if you familiar with C++ and Qt basics.